# Populate AutoCompleteTextView from a remote API

Tags: xamarin.android, autocompletetextview

I have a filter dialog on my Xamarin app that'll have an autocompletetextview to give the user a searchable way to find an item.

the issue is that the autocomplete data will be from an API and I'm having a hard time finding a good solution that works.

I'm following [this](https://www.truiton.com/2018/06/android-autocompletetextview-suggestions-from-webservice-call/) tutorial and a little lost on getting the filtering to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just want to do is set the data from(web api) into your AutoCompleteTextview's Adapter

A simple example ：

in **activity** :

```
[Activity(Label = "AutoComplextActivity", MainLauncher = true)]
public class AutoComplextActivity : Activity
{
    private ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.autocomplext_layout);
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.id_autotextView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);
        acTextView.Adapter=adapter;
        GetData();                 
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        //get data form web api,for example the data is below
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("beijing1");
        data.Add("beijing2");
        data.Add("beijing3");
        data.Add("shanghai1");
        data.Add("shanghai2");
        data.Add("guangzhou1");
        data.Add("shenzhen");
        data.Add("adadadsgua");

        //add data into adapter
        adapter.AddAll(data);
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```